# Graficar mapa Argentina con archivo shp - Python

Tags: python, mapa

Dejo el código para graficar el mapa de Argentina usando un archivo shp (puede ser de cualquier país). Estuve bastante tiempo tratando de hacer el mapa, y al final todo se resumía a 5 líneas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader as sf
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature as cfeature


#El archivo shp lo pueden encontrar en la página del Instituto Geográfico Nacional (IGN)
fname = 'C:/Users/Desktop/provincia.shp'

fig, ax = plt.subplots( 1, 1, subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()), figsize=[12,14]  )
shape_feature = cfeature(sf(fname).geometries(), ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='black')
ax.add_feature(shape_feature, facecolor= 'none')

#Defino los ejes (lon min y max, lat min y max)
ax.set_extent([-76, -53, -57, -20])
```

El mapa queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Magali, qué bueno que lo consiguieras. De todos modos, ¿publicas para compartir la solución? Si es así, sería mejor plantear la pregunta de forma clara y luego poner el código _solucionador_ en una respuesta, tal y como se explica en [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Si no haces eso, vamos a tener que cerrar la pregunta, como no es una pregunta...

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una pregunta tal como lo establece el [help/on-topic].

Comment: Ok. Indiquenme como puedo cerrar la pregunta. Gracias